# ubuntu 12.04 shuts down due to HDMI?

Tags: crash

i am running ubuntu 12.04 and it has started to shut down randomly.

I check my syslog on noticed this:

```
kernel: [132227.799570] HDMI: audio coding type 0 not expected 
kernel: Kernel logging (proc) stopped. 
rsyslogd: [origin software="rsyslogd" swVersion="5.8.6" x-pid="772" x-info="http://www.rsyslog.com"] exiting on s
```

This is clearly when ubuntu crashed as far as i can tell.
Does this mean my HDMI driver caused the crash?
Where do i go with this info?

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend updating to Ubuntu 14.04 since a lot of work has gone into HDMI, graphics and sound in the newer kernels and should work a lot better on your system without error...

Comment: Ok i started that this am and it is still updating 6 hours later.  I seems to be unpacking packages and they are taking an extremely long time.  Is this normal?  I suppose I have no other option at this point than to let if finish.

Comment: Updating can take a while depending on your computer although installing a fresh copy would have taken under 20 minutes...